# How do I remove lines with grep based on conditions?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep

I would like to use grep to remove all lines in a file ending with `]:` such that the next line starts with `I` or EOF is reached.

That is: Remove all lines that end with a `]:` **and** is followed by a line starting with `I` of end-of-file.

Given the following:

```
I am an invalid line ]:
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
I am an invalid line ]:
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
```

The output should be

```
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
```

Notice that the 1st and 8th lines `I am in invalid line ]:` were removed because it ended with `]:` and the next line began with `I`

Comment: why are `some text` valid, if valid lines only have `I` and `:]` and **NOT** `invalid` in them?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v 'invalid' file.txt
```

That should do it. With -v you are asking to select lines not matching that criteria.

Example:

```
$ cat ~/test.txt
I am an invalid line ]:
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
I am an invalid line ]:
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text

$ grep -v 'invalid' ~/test.txt
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
```

**Update based on change of question**

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/]:\nI/]:xxx\nI/g' ~/test.txt | grep -v 'xxx'
```

With this method, I replace `]:\nI` with `]:xxx\nI`. See how I injected xxx behind the line ending with `]:`-newline-I? Then I grep and remove those lines that have `xxx`

Comment: I updated the question. The format may change. Characters ]: and I at the beginning of the headers will not change.

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of different format and desired output? Once done, please add a comment and I will update my answer

Comment: @Bobo. I see! I think I understand the question now but I don't know how to do that with lookbehind regex. Hopefully someone good with regex will help answer

Comment: @Bobo I added an example with sed and grep that might help you also

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work for your requirement:

```
awk '/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next} pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1){print prec; pno=0} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
I am a valid line ]:
some text
some text
some text
```

**Breakup:**

```
/\]:$/{pno=NR;prec=$0;next}  # if ]: is at line end store line # and line and move to next
pno && !(/^I/ && NR==pno+1)  # if next row starts with I and we have prev vars set
{print prec; pno=0}          # print previous line and rest prev line # to 0
1                            # default action to print current record
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers seem like overkill to me, so maybe I'm missing something, but:

```
sed 'N;/]:\nI/D'
```